# Plotting low in tradingview giving wrong output

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am trying to plot the low price ein trading view but the plots are very counterintuitive and confusing. can someone please help.

In the 15m chart the blue line created at low at 82.9990 however i can clearly see bar closing lower than that in the previous day.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcGFj.png)

Moreover these data points lower than 882.999 arre not visible in the daily timeframe. ss attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssVrX.png)
`

```
//@version=5
strategy("xyz usdinr", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close=true)

timeAllowed = input.session("0930-1630", "Allowed hours")
daysAllowed = input.string("23456")
trade_limit=1933
timeIsAllowed = time(timeframe.period, timeAllowed + ":" + daysAllowed,timezone = "Asia/Kolkata")
plot(series=timeIsAllowed ? low : na, color=color.orange, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_circles)

var int tradesCount = 0// Calculate previous day high and low
prevHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
prevLow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(series=prevHigh , color=color.rgb(255, 51, 231), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line)
plot(series=prevLow , color=color.rgb(85, 70, 255), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line)
```

i tried playin around with lookahead and low[0],low[-1]. low[2] etc. but no success/